# Смержить объекты из 2-х листов по определенным полям

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть 2 листа объектов, мне надо смержить объекты внутри первого листа с объектами из второго листа, грубо говоря дополнить объекты первого листа не достающими данными.

Например, есть объект

{name: "sample", birthdate: "13.01.1994", email: "example@example.com", lastname: null}

{name: null, birthdate: "13.01.1994", email: "example@example.com", lastname: "examplelast"}

Мержим по полям birthdate и email получаем:
{name: "sample", birthdate: "13.01.1994", email: "example@example.com", lastname: "examplelast"}

Подскажите пожалуйста как это нормально сделать, массивы могут быть достаточно большими

Comment: Непонятно какие листы.

Comment: пусть будет `ArrayList<User>`

Comment: а если будет несколько записей которые можно смерджить с первой , но будут содержать, например, разный name? Как их тогда мерджить - в каком порядке? Вам надо сначала правила объединения четче сформулировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть поле однозначно идентифицирующее записи, то это несложно.

Для начала нужен метод знающий как мерджить объекты. Можно реализовать эту логику в лямбде или определить как статический метод класса, проводящего обработку данных,  но лучше всего - определить этот метод в классе обрабатываемых данных:

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String birthdate;
    private String email;

    ...  // Конструкторы, аксессоры и прочее

    public User merge(User other) {
        name = this.name == null ? other.name : this.name;
        ... // Та же операция для других полей
        return this;
    }
}
```

Теперь можно создать коллектор, объединяющий записи из двух потоков

```
List<User> merged = Stream.concat(users1.stream(), users2.stream())
                          .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toMap(
                              User::getEmail,
                              Function.identity(),
                              User::merge),
                            m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```